# Linux Move files from base path to multiple paths in a loop

Tags: linux, bash

Can you please provide some pointers to move files from Base path to multiple paths in efficient way.Folder Structure is already created.

/Path/AdminUser/User1/1111/Reports/aaa.txt to /Path/User1/1111/Reports/aaa.txt
/Path/AdminUser/User1/2222/Reports/bbb.txt to /Path/User1/2222/Reports/bbb.txt
/Path/AdminUser/User2/3333/Reports/ccc.txt to /Path/User2/3333/Reports/ccc.txt
/Path/AdminUser/User2/3333/Reports/ddd.txt to /Path/User2/3333/Reports/ddd.txt

I don't want to move directory structure. I want to move files from that source path to destination path on daily basis. I would need pointer to write a bash script to make sure aaa.txt would exactly go and sit only from `/Path/AdminUser/User1/1111/Reports/` to `/Path/User1/1111/Reports/........`

Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/Path"
subs= `ls $dir1/AdminUser`
for i in $subs; do
  mv $dir1/AdminUser/$i/*/Reports $dir1/$i/*/Reports 
done
```

Comment: Does not `mv /Path/Admin/User* /Path/.` work?

Comment: @tivn - Since I was looking to move files recursively on daily basis not folder structure, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=/home/jahid/newfolder
for i in "$dir1"/AdminUser/*; do
if [[ -d $i && ! -L $i ]]; then 
dir2="${i##*/}"
for j in "$i"/*; do 
if [[ -d $j && ! -L $j ]]; then 
j="${j##*/}"
[[ -d "$dir1"/"$dir2"/"$j" ]] || mkdir -p "$dir1"/"$dir2"/"$j"
mv "$i"/"$j"/Reports "$dir1"/"$dir2"/"$j"/
fi
done
fi
done
```

Edit: Added code to check for existing directory structure, if not present, it will create it.

Comment: Nope my question was definitely not that.

Comment: I want to move files from that source path to destination path on daily basis. I would need pointer to write a bash script to make sure aaa.txt would exactly go and sit only from /Path/AdminUser/User1/1111/Reports/ to /Path/User1/1111/Reports/........                                                                            Ex: #!/bin/bash

dir1="/Path"

subs= `ls $dir1/AdminUser`

for i in $subs; do
  mv $dir1/AdminUser/$i/*/Reports $dir1/$i/*/Reports 
done

Comment: @Karthik Edited per your comment. I haven't tested it, so if any problem, let me know.

Comment: thanks for inputs but it threw error--/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: no such file or directory. Let me check on paths.....We have 2 level of loops...../Path/AdminUser/Users(firstlevel)/id(secondlevel)/Daily...

Comment: Did you say `Daily`? If the Last folder is `Daily` you need to change `Reporsts` to `Daily` too, in the code.

Comment: Hi Jahid, please ignore Daily part. I observe its failing at first if clause and exiting out.if [[ -d $i && ! -L $i ]]; then

Comment: Steps done:  $pwd  -->/path                                                            
$mkdir -p  AdminUser/User1/111/Reports                                               
$ touch AdminUser/User1/111/Reports/abc.txt                                                      
$ mkdir -p  User1/111/Reports                                                                                      
Changed the path to my path  /path  and ran script.                                                   
Added few print statements and its not validating first if
if [[ -d $i && ! -L $i ]]; --Condition fails here

Comment: My bad, i gave path incorrectly, your script works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your quick response and efforts on it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be achievable without scripting. Have a look at rsync.

```
rsync -r /Path/AdminUser/* /NewPath/
```

Comment: Thanks Sash, rsync works, but since in my scenario, its not just folder structure, I have to make sure security & ownership of file system isn't affected so I was inclined to use script to move files in loop from parent path to child path.

Comment: You can

1. use rsync with a few options (I always use -avuHAX, it does a few things and keeps ownership.
2. use getfacl and setfacl to save and set the permissions.